# How to roll-back a recent edit?

Tags: support, editing

After mistaking two similar characters, I made an inappropriate change to [genesis - What is the significance of the insertion of the 5th letter of the Hebrew alphabet into the names of Abraham and Sarah? - Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/19627/what-is-the-significance-of-the-insertion-of-the-5th-letter-of-the-hebrew-alphab).

But when I look at the edits, it offers me only "Source, Edit, and Link", without the "Rollback" that is available for other edits.

How should I undo that edit?

---

Meanwhile, I edited it again to remove my changes.

And now I see that my first edit *now* allows Rollback.

Is something broken, or am I missing something, or what?

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure about this, but I have noticed times that fast edits have been “squashed” sometimes. If that is how the software is designed, then it is to avoid an infinite edit history of every forgotten character we change five seconds after saving.

I would need to ask the software team at SE, and they have better things to do than satisfy my curiosity. As a developer myself, I would certainly want to squash frequent edits if for no other reason than to keep the database small.

So just guessing, but it’s possible the edits could have been squashed.

Comment: In this case I ended up doing two edits rather than one edit and a rollback, so whatever was going on it resulted in *more* edits than necessary.

Comment: @RayButterworth that's life. They're re-doing the entire software platform anyway. Things like that will probably get taken care of. For now, we've all got bigger fish to fry. But, a lot of people may get their curiosity satisfied because you asked about this. It certainly is a thing. Glad to have you on the site!